# Password in the process memory but not in the heap dump

Tags: java, jvm, passwords

I've stumbled recently on a issue with java processes where one could use a tool like http://processhacker.sourceforge.net to inspect the memory of the runtime application. The tool - reveals the password used to authenticate in the application. I've investigate the issue and the password seems to zeroed out after it's used. I tried to do a heap dump using Java Mission Control (with GC disabled) and see if I can retrieve the passsword. Using the Eclipse Memory Tool I ran simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM char[] c WHERE toString(c).startsWith("mypasswordsample")
```

But that did not yield any result, and the password was still visible in the process hacker after an hour or so. If I do the heap dump with the GC enabled - process hacker seems to no longer find the password.

What is doing JVM behind the scenes? Why I can't find the password in the live objects? Can I do some sort of dump to see where is this password stored, who created it and why wasn't zeroed out?

Comment: "who created it and why wasn't zeroed out" - that is totally up to the application. You won't be able to find answers to that question in a memory dump.

Comment: You are right, but I was hoping to find the name of the attribute or something that will help me trace the issue down in the code.

Comment: Password data may still reside in inactive survivor space of YoungGen, in native memory or somewhere else depending on how it is used and cleared. It will be easier to say if you provide relevant piece of code. Does Process Hacker show an address where it finds the data?

Comment: The code base is very large, it will be impractical for the purpose of the question. Yes - Process Hacker shows an address, but I'm not sure how can that help me.

Comment: does `toString(c)`  gives you String representation of `char[]` content or it just invokes `toString()` on `char[]` ?

Comment: Acording to http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Freference%2Foqlsyntaxselect.html it gives you the value of an obiect - i.e the content. So it will be the string representation of char array.

Comment: The GC keeps live object and cleans up the rest, if using the GC makes it go away, its not a live object.

Comment: First of all, check if the address belongs to Java heap (which part of it). JVM will print the heap layout in response to `Ctrl+Break` signal. Alternatively specify `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC` to print the heap layout on each GC.

Comment: If the password was ever stored in an String (for instance, in an intermediate step while reading it from stdin and storing it in a char[]), it might still be present in the String cache, even if the object is no longer referenced. The query you use will not show it because you ask for a cha[].

Answer (score 1):

This is too specific to answer, but many passwords (particularly with JAAS) will use a character array instead of a String and explicitly zero out the characters after use. So if you got a heap dump while they were logging on you might see it; but if not, then you wouldn't. See the [PasswordCallback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/PasswordCallback.html) from JAAS that uses this mechanism.

(An array of characters is used because an array is mutable; therefore you can go through afterwards and set each character to a space or `\0` once it's been used to authenticate. That way even if the GC doesn't clean it up quickly, the contents of the memory shouldn't hold the data for snooping processes.